# How to make Fabric use the bash shell insread of the default shell?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, ssh, fabric

I am trying to use Fabric (Python3). My remove server uses "ksh" shell but I need to use "bash" shell. How do I achieve this using Fabric ?

Answer (score 1):

I do this with an environment variable called `FABRIC_RUN_SHELL`. For example:

```
export FABRIC_RUN_SHELL=/usr/bin/bash
```

You can also configure it directly in your fabfile.py:

```
@task
def my_task(c):
    pass

@task
def my_task2(c):
    pass

ns = Collection(my_task)
ns.configure({'run': {'shell': '/usr/bin/bash'}})
```

There are other options too, such as loading from a config file. Confusingly, all the details are in the [Invoke configuration docs](https://docs.pyinvoke.org/en/stable/concepts/configuration.html) and not the Fabric docs. The fact that you use the `FABRIC_` prefix instead of `INVOKE_` is mentioned in the [Fabric configuration docs](https://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/api/config.html#module-fabric.config).